# Is there a way to fix the value of an element in an xml?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to constrain an xml element through the xsd to say, "A", "B" or "C"?

Comment: What is an "alpha digit"? Seems like a contradiction in terms?

Comment: Sorry, I mean 1 character - in other words, is it possible to constrain an xml element through the xsd to say, "A", "B" or "C"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you're wanting to restrict it to just a single letter (but any letter), or just to the letters A, B, or C, but yes, either of those are possible:

```
<xs:element name="def">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ghi">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```